# How to check if a file exists in the Documents directory in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How to check if a file exists in the Documents directory in `Swift`?

I am using `[ .writeFilePath ]` method to save an image into the Documents directory and I want to load it every time the app is launched. But I have a default image if there is no saved image.

But I just cant get my head around how to use the `[ func fileExistsAtPath(_:) ]` function. Could someone give an example of using the function with a path argument passed into it.

I believe I don't need to paste any code in there as this is a generic question. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

**Swift 4.x** version

```
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    if let pathComponent = url.appendingPathComponent("nameOfFileHere") {
        let filePath = pathComponent.path
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            print("FILE AVAILABLE")
        } else {
            print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
        }
    } else {
        print("FILE PATH NOT AVAILABLE")
    }
```

**Swift 3.x** version

```
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent("nameOfFileHere").path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
        print("FILE AVAILABLE")
    } else {
        print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
    }
```

**Swift 2.x** version, need to use **URLByAppendingPathComponent**

```
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let filePath = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent("nameOfFileHere").path!
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(filePath) {
        print("FILE AVAILABLE")
    } else {
        print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the answer was updated so the absoluteString comments seem obsolete.

Comment: presumably those comments were that absoluteString doesn't work from a URL, but path does, which is what I found!

Comment: is the same logic when searching for file in .libraryDirectory? I ask because I tried and it cannot find it, even if the file was successfully written into it.

Answer (score 34):

Check the below code:

**Swift 1.2**

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

let getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("SavedFile.jpg")

let checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(getImagePath))
{
    println("FILE AVAILABLE");
}
else
{
    println("FILE NOT AVAILABLE");
}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
let paths = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
let getImagePath = paths.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SavedFile.jpg")

let checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath("\(getImagePath)"))
{
    print("FILE AVAILABLE");
}
else
{
    print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE");
}
```

Comment: @SaqibOmer try casting paths as NSString rather than String. `var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString`

Comment: @PREMKUMAR Why that strange string interpolation? You could use `absoluteString` to convert `NSURL` to `path` but it would be better to just keep the path as a string (`NSString`) like you do in Swift 1.2.

Comment: I found this answer to work properly with Swift 2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36897617/1245231

Answer (score 30):

Nowadays (2016) Apple recommends more and more to use the URL related API of `NSURL`, `NSFileManager` etc.

To get the documents directory in iOS and **Swift 2** use

```
let documentDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, 
                                 inDomain: .UserDomainMask, 
                        appropriateForURL: nil, 
                                   create: true)
```

The `try!` is safe in this case because this standard directory is guaranteed to exist.

Then append the appropriate path component for example an `sqlite` file

```
let databaseURL = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyDataBase.sqlite")
```

Now check if the file exists with `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError` of `NSURL`.

```
let fileExists = databaseURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil)
```

If you need the error pass the `NSError` pointer to the parameter.

```
var error : NSError?
let fileExists = databaseURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error)
if !fileExists { print(error) }
```

**Swift 3+:**

```
let documentDirectoryURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, 
                                in: .userDomainMask, 
                    appropriateFor: nil, 
                            create: true)

let databaseURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("MyDataBase.sqlite")
```

`checkResourceIsReachable` is marked as *can throw*

```
do {
    let fileExists = try databaseURL.checkResourceIsReachable()
    // handle the boolean result
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

To consider only the boolean return value and ignore the error use the nil-coalescing operator

```
let fileExists = (try? databaseURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false
```

Comment: I think in Swift 3 this is now `checkResourceIsReachable()` and just returns `Bool` for `URL` type.

Comment: The problem I found is that you never seem to get a "false" value from checkResourceIsReachable() in Swift3, just an exception if the file is not there. I'm not very happy using an API where a lot of calls will result in an exception instead of a simple return value.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner  Swift's `try - catch` pattern does not throw exceptions. It's not comparable with exceptions in Objective-C. It's an efficient error handling system.

Comment: It's more efficient I know, but conceptually I do not like it. I don't mind something throwing an exception for - an exception. But a file not existing is NOT an exception.  It is a common case and should result in a false return value, not some kind of aberration with a wrapped Error object that had to be created.  It may not seem like much but if you have tens of thousands of files to check the burden is too high.

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 4.2**

```
extension URL    {
    func checkFileExist() -> Bool {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: self.path) {
            print("FILE AVAILABLE")
            return true
        } else {
            print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

**Using: -**

```
if fileUrl.checkFileExist() {
    // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 18):

works at **Swift 5**

```
    do {
        let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let fileUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("userInfo").appendingPathExtension("sqlite3")
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileUrl.path) {
            print("FILE AVAILABLE")
        } else {
            print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

where `"userInfo"` - file's name, and `"sqlite3"` - file's extension

Answer (score 16):

It's pretty user friendly. Just work with NSFileManager's defaultManager singleton and then use the `fileExistsAtPath()` method, which simply takes a string as an argument, and returns a Bool, allowing it to be placed directly in the if statement.

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String
let myFilePath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("nameOfMyFile")

let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if (manager.fileExistsAtPath(myFilePath)) {
    // it's here!!
}
```

Note that the downcast to String isn't necessary in Swift 2.

Comment: ♦ please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503283/how-to-get-nsurl-on-specific-file-from-document-directory-in-swift . I don't know which code need to write.

Answer (score 8):

### Swift 5

```
extension FileManager {
    class func fileExists(filePath: String) -> Bool {
        var isDirectory = ObjCBool(false)
        return self.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath, isDirectory: &isDirectory)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative/recommended Code Pattern in **Swift 3** would be:

1. Use URL instead of FileManager
2. Use of exception handling

   ```
   func verifyIfSqliteDBExists(){
       let docsDir     : URL       = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
       let dbPath      : URL       = docsDir.appendingPathComponent("database.sqlite")

       do{
           let sqliteExists : Bool = try dbPath.checkResourceIsReachable()
           print("An sqlite database exists at this path :: \(dbPath.path)")

       }catch{
           print("SQLite NOT Found at :: \(strDBPath)")
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Very simple:
If your path is a URL instance convert to string by 'path' method.

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    var isDir: ObjCBool = false
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: yourURLPath.path, isDirectory: &isDir) {
        if isDir.boolValue {
            //it's a Directory path
        }else{
            //it's a File path
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of **Swift 3** beginners:

1. Swift 3 has done away with most of the NextStep syntax
2. So NSURL, NSFilemanager, NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain are no longer used
3. Instead use URL and FileManager
4. NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain is not needed
5. Instead use FileManager.default.urls

Here is a code sample to verify if a file named "database.sqlite" exists in application document directory:

```
func findIfSqliteDBExists(){

    let docsDir     : URL       = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let dbPath      : URL       = docsDir.appendingPathComponent("database.sqlite")
    let strDBPath   : String    = dbPath.path
    let fileManager : FileManager   = FileManager.default

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath:strDBPath){
        print("An sqlite database exists at this path :: \(strDBPath)")
    }else{
        print("SQLite NOT Found at :: \(strDBPath)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me in swift4:

```
func existingFile(fileName: String) -> Bool {

    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    if let pathComponent = url.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)") {
        let filePath = pathComponent.path
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) 

       {

        return true

        } else {

        return false

        }

    } else {

        return false

        }


}
```

You can check with this call:

```
   if existingFile(fileName: "yourfilename") == true {

            // your code if file exists

           } else {

           // your code if file does not exist

           }
```

I hope it is useful for someone. @;-]

Comment: What if the user do not want to just only check the document directory? and want to search a generic path

Answer (score 0):

You must add a "/" slash before filename, or you get path like ".../DocumentsFilename.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** example:

```
var filePath: String {
    //manager lets you examine contents of a files and folders in your app.
    let manager = FileManager.default

    //returns an array of urls from our documentDirectory and we take the first
    let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    //print("this is the url path in the document directory \(String(describing: url))")

    //creates a new path component and creates a new file called "Data" where we store our data array
    return(url!.appendingPathComponent("Data").path)
}
```

I put the check in my loadData function which I called in viewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()
}
```

Then I defined loadData below.

```
func loadData() {
    let manager = FileManager.default

    if manager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
        print("The file exists!")

        //Do what you need with the file. 
        ourData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as! Array<DataObject>         
    } else {
        print("The file DOES NOT exist! Mournful trumpets sound...")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what was needed but it might help someone. A simple Swift 5+ `URL` extension for checking if the file at that `URL` exists:

```
extension URL {
    func fileExist() -> Bool {
        FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: self.path)
    }
}
```