# How to get NSURL on specific file from document directory in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, directory, nsurl

I getting files from document directory with the help of `NSFileManager`. I got an array of file names and I can pass them to another controller. Still I want to pass `NSURL` on specific file from my `UITableViewCell` as I pass names of these files. My files are mp3. Please help me.

```
 var listOfMP3Files: Array<String!>? // for Cell data

    func fetchFilesFromFolder() {
        var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        var folderPathURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)[0] as! NSURL

        var documentsContent = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(folderPathURL.path!, error: nil)
        println(documentsContent)

        if var directoryURLs = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folderPathURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles, error: nil) {
            println(directoryURLs)

            var mp3Files = directoryURLs.map(){ $0.lastPathComponent }.filter(){ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }

            listOfMP3Files = mp3Files
            println(mp3Files)
        }
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var playerVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! AVPlayerVC
    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var objectForPass = listOfMP3Files![indexPath!.row] // default
    if segue.identifier == "listenMusic" {
        playerVC.object = objectForPass 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I updated my code and I can to get files of jpg type. But I don't know how to get mp3 files.

My updated code

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var playerVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayMusicViewController
    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var objectForPass = listOfMP3Files![indexPath!.row] // default
    //

    var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as? String
    var getImage = path?.stringByAppendingPathComponent(objectForPass)
    var image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: getImage!)

    if segue.identifier == "listenMusic" {
        playerVC.musicFile = objectForPass
        playerVC.end = image 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2**
I edited my code and I can to pass `NSURL` on mp3 files and in another `UIViewController` I can play them.

Below there is a edited code

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var playerVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayMusicViewController
        var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        var objectForPass = listOfMP3Files![indexPath!.row] // default
        //

      /*  var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as? String
        var getImage = path?.stringByAppendingPathComponent(objectForPass)
        var image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: getImage!) */
        //
        var fileM = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        var wayToFile = fileM.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
        var passMusicFileURL: NSURL?

        if let documentPath: NSURL = wayToFile.first as? NSURL {
            let musicFile = documentPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(objectForPass)
            println(musicFile)
            passMusicFileURL = musicFile
        }
        if segue.identifier == "listenMusic" {
           // playerVC.musicFile = objectForPass
            playerVC.end = passMusicFileURL
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my question

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var playerVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayMusicViewController
    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var objectForPass = listOfMP3Files![indexPath!.row] // default
    //

  /*  var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as? String
    var getImage = path?.stringByAppendingPathComponent(objectForPass)
    var image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: getImage!) */
    //
    var fileM = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var wayToFile = fileM.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
    var passMusicFileURL: NSURL?

    if let documentPath: NSURL = wayToFile.first as? NSURL {
        let musicFile = documentPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(objectForPass)
        println(musicFile)
        passMusicFileURL = musicFile
    }
    if segue.identifier == "listenMusic" {
       // playerVC.musicFile = objectForPass
        playerVC.end = passMusicFileURL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create the full file URL in a separate intermediate statement and you will find the problem.

If you do not have independent statements debugging is very hard.

`folderPathURL.path` is incorrect.

First create the entire file path, then create f  file URL from it.

Example:

```
let name = "aFileName"
var filePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
println("\nfilePath: \(filePath)")

filePath = filePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)
println("\nfilePath: \(filePath)")

var filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
println("\nfilePathURL: \(filePathURL!)")
```

Output:

> filePath: /Users/zaph/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/264B31F6-3A28-4C75-9205-3558BBF54DED/data/Containers/Data/Application/0048403F-C8DE-4EE7-83CF-6AE7CCBAF090/Documents
>
> filePath: /Users/zaph/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/264B31F6-3A28-4C75-9205-3558BBF54DED/data/Containers/Data/Application/0048403F-C8DE-4EE7-83CF-6AE7CCBAF090/Documents/aFileName
>
> filePathURL: file:///Users/zaph/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/264B31F6-3A28-4C75-9205-3558BBF54DED/data/Containers/Data/Application/0048403F-C8DE-4EE7-83CF-6AE7CCBAF090/Documents/aFileName

With the intermediate statements each step can be validated.