# How can I bring in data from a text file on disk without adding it to the project?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to read in a file from disk and parse its data into a nice format. However, the function is not returning anything. It returns an empty array. Why is this?

Note: I've been tinkering around with this and I've managed to simplify the previous 2 functions to just this one.

*The function:*

```
func openFile(_ fileName:String, _ fileType:String) -> [(Double, Double)] {

        let file = fileName + fileType //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

        var text2: String = ""

        if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

            let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

            //reading
            do {
                text2 = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            }
            catch {/* error handling here */}


        }

        var pairs = [(Double,Double)]()
        var words: [String] = []

        for line in (text2.components(separatedBy: "\n").dropFirst()){
            if line != "" {
                words = line.components(separatedBy: "\t")
                pairs.append((Double(words[0])!,Double(words[1])!))

            }
        }

        return pairs
    }
```

Comment: @dfd do I need the full path??

Comment: @dfd didn't work. I passed `/home/user/Downloads/filename` and `url` was still `nil`

Comment: @dfd ok thank you!!!

Comment: Here's a question with an answer that may give you a good start. It searches a few directories, builds a URL and path, and then uses FileManager to see if the file exists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181699/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-the-documents-directory-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: @loltospoon Bundle.main.url only returns urls for files that were bundled into your app. You can't get a url for files located at the downloads directory using it.

Comment: @LeoDabus well...that's a pretty big problem then haha woops

Comment: `let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent(filename_val).appendingPathExtension(fileExtension_val)`

Comment: Why don't you just hide the extension using the method I suggested at your last question ?

Comment: @LeoDabus What will hiding the extension do?

Comment: If you get the file info in finder it has a hide extension check mark. my extension allows you to select or deselect it so if you look at the file in your finder it won't show the extension, the same applies to the open/save panel

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh I just needed to move on to some other parts that need fixing. If it so happens that your method is efficient in this project I'll implement it.

Comment: @LeoDabus for your `let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent(filename_val)‌​.appendingPathExtens‌​ion(fileExtension_va‌​l)` code, it throws the error: `Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'`

Comment: `let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent(filename_val).appendingPathExtension(fileExtensio‌​n_va‌​l)` it is correct probably an invisible character there

Comment: @LeoDabus I cannot find this invisible character. I copied your code directly. It seems to be pointing to the `.` after `(filename_val)`

Comment: This is for Swift 3 btw. Maybe your code is for a previous version of Swift?

Comment: Try retyping it again if the problem persists letting Xcode autocomplete it for you. I am using Swift 3.0.2 • Xcode 8.2.1. `let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent(filename).appendingPathExtension(fileExtensio‌​n)`

Comment: it autofilled `.appendingPathComponent`