# Check if JSON file exists in directory - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a file in my project directory in Xcode. I am new to swift and all I would like to do is check if the file exists.

[Picture of project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz0Zm.png)

I created a resources directory and put it in the project. I added my file "GEOJson.json" and I just want to check for its existence and have a boolean value returned.

I am eventually going to need to read from the JSON file and import the contents into my project.

Extra:

Eventually this file is going to need to be pulled from a remote server as it will be constantly updating and inside it will be objects with GPS coordinates that need to be added to my map kit. The GEOJson file will be sitting on a mesh network that we set up and the app will need to pull the file off a directory on the network when connected to it and update the map. The end goal is that the file's existence is checked for on the server, if it exists it will be pulled periodically and the contents will update said map markers. If anybody has any idea how to do this the help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a file exists in the Documents directory in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181699/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-the-documents-directory-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
if let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GEOJson", ofType: "json", inDirectory: "Resources") {

   print(file)
}
```

//

If you want to edit it then you have to copy / download - it out of main Bundle say in Documents , then process it there